# Method in rails model not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, associations

I have made the models users and schools, and one of the schools has the name Harvard. I want to be able to return all Users who's school is Harvard. This section of code is in the user.rb file.

```
def self.harvard_students
    return User.where.School(name: 'Harvard')
end
```

Comment: You should provide a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do that like this:

```
# in models/user.rb
scope :harvard_students, -> { joins(:school).where(schools: { name: 'Harvard' }) }
```

Or as a class method:

```
def self.harvard_students
  joins(:school).where(schools: { name: 'Harvard' })
end
```

used like this:

```
User.harvard_students
```

Comment: Thanks, but im trying to use it using self though

Comment: I see no benefit in a class method, but I updated my answer to address this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your relationships are setup like the below then this should work. I'd advise against a hard coded `harvard_students` model unless you are really sure you want to treat those students differently.

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :students
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :school

  def self.harvard_students
    School.find_by(name: "Harvard").users
  end
end

#....
User.harvard_students
```